# Getting coordinate for Matlab image processing 

Tags: image, matlab, coordinate

I create a program in MATLAB that loaded a video and then selected an object. After that video start to run I can follow the object that I have been selected. The object is tracking in the binary video. usually it's just 3 or 4 pixel, but the coordinate of those pixels (I mean object). How can I do this?

Answer (score 3):

```
get(hpanel,'position')
```

Will return a 4-element vector with `[left bottom width height]` of the rectangle.